# Why Gedit's hash symbol is expanded and interpreted wrongly in internet browsers?

Tags: debian, character-encoding, gedit, ascii

I copy-paste Gedit-hash (`#`) in a part of filepath into internet browser to read PDF file unsuccessfully: no file found with Gedit-hash symbol. 
Inputing there directly the hash symbol from the keyboard is consireded correct. 
Copy-pasting the gedit-hash to Vim shows Ascii 035 correctly, also tested on the ASCII tool [here](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/). 
Example filepath misinterpreted in Internet browser where `#` expands to `%23` wrongly

```
/home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf#page=605
```

Do

1. Copy the filepath to Gedit
2. Copy the filepath from Gedit
3. Paste the filepath to any internet browser
4. Output: `#` symbol is expanded to `%23`

Methods inserting filepath which are correctly interpreted

- type hash directly to the internet browser field

OS: Debian 8.7
Internet browsers: Google Chrome 58.0.x, Firefox latest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNIX filenames are not URLs.

You can see that '#' is not interpreted in unix filenames, but it is in URLs.

```
$ ls '/home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf#page=605'
ls: cannot access '/home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf#page=605': No such file or directory
$ curl '/home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf#page=605'
curl: (3) <url> malformed
$ curl 'file:///home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf#page=605'
curl: (37) Couldn't open file /home/masi/Documents/Edition.pdf
```

Firefox is applying the correct escaping, to protect the filename character `#` from being interpreted as delimiting a fragment in the URL.

Comment: How can you prevent such a behaviour? I want to use my internet browser to read documents.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Use URLs.

Comment: Documents are in my filesystem.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 `file:///` URLs.